# Can't change chat room access

Tags: support, chat

I've created a private [chat room](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/464/sharepoint-moderators) and want to make another [couple](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/users/2070/kit-menke) of [users](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/users/11/anders-rask) co-owners. I've tried entering a user ID, pasting in their profile URL, and searching.

[image: Add owner dialog]

Once I click the "make owner" button, the page refreshes and nothing happens. I am behind a firewall but haven't had any other issues using chat. I've also tried giving "explicit write access" which didn't work either. Browser is IE8.

Any ideas?

Comment: As an addendum, one of the users I'm trying to add just entered the room. They're a mod so that could be why. Not showing on the Owners list though.

Comment: SE mods can enter any room owned by their site, and all default rooms

Comment: @Michael So the best way to notify SE mods of a private chat room is just to `@`tag them and invite them in I guess?

Comment: You have to @@ them, but yes, I guess so. It'll also show up on your site's mod page, so they might notice it there

Answer (score 4, accepted):

OK, I've added them as co-owners; I *think* the confusion is a subtle difference between chat ids and site-specific ids, which can be different (due to chat.SE having users from multiple sites). I'll add this to my list to investigate, but I **suspect** that finding the user ***in chat*** and using their id from chat may have worked. But like I say, I'll look into it.

For reference, I added them by entering their *names* into the second input - it found them right away and added them successfully.

Comment: I just ran into this too. Copying the user's SP.SE profile URL did NOT work. I had to find their Chat ID instead.